# Blender failing to open saves using cycles render. (OpenGL 3.3 or higher error)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, opengl

I have been trying to get back into blender but most of my saves aren't opening. I get the "Blender - unsupported Graphics card. the graphics card needs OpenGL 3.3..." If i save the file as Eevee they open fine. I have updated all my drivers with clean installs. I have tried disabling the graphics card in the system settings and I am still running into the same issue.

Hardware: Intel 6700k and 2x 980 ti's 
Software: Blender 2.8 through Steam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a bug with SLI. If you go into the Nvidia control panel and manually select 1 GPU for openGL it resolves the error.

[image]